# SSH file transfer between VM host and client

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, ftp

I have a Windows 7 host, with FileZilla. The client VM, a RedHat 6.3, has IP address `192.168.93.130` (determined using `ifconfig`).

[image]

I have tried using the "Quickconnect" feature of FileZilla, entering the IP address, port 22 and my shell login and username.

This is what I get:

[image]

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you ping the client's IP? Have you check the firewall on the client? Is SSHD running on the client? There are a few more things that could be going wrong, but those are the first three I would check, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Ping does not work... Damn it. How can I check the client firewall? I just have access to this one command prompt.

Comment: run "iptables -L" in that shell. If the firewall is "off" you should see only three chains listed with no rules in any of the three. To turn it off, run "service iptables stop". To keep it off after a reboot, then run "chkconfig iptables off".

Comment: Actually, half the time my ping says "Request timed out." and the other half "ip dest net unreachable"

Comment: What is your windows host IP?

Comment: I'm running Windows 7. How can I find the IP address?

Comment: If you can't get the IP address of the host, I'm not sure I can help you.

Comment: John, I'm not exactly sure what you're talking about. My internet IP address is `109.222.138.238`, but I don't see how this has anything to do with my SSH problem, which is local to my computer. Are you talking about `127.0.0.1`? Confused, sorry.

Comment: Your Windows computer needs to have a 192.168.93.$FOO IP address or a route to that network. Otherwise, you have no connectivity from host to guest.

Comment: randomblue: open cmd in Windows 7 and type: "ipconfig" without the quotes. This should return the IP for your Local Area Network Connection. It is likely 192.168.x.x (we need you to fill in the x's). I agree with John, I think your VM is using another subnet (192.168.93.0/24) and your Windows 7 host is unable to route to it. If your Windows IP is 192.168.1.x, can you change the IP on your linux box to something in that range? maybe 192.168.1.130?

Comment: My Windows host IP is 192.168.1.15. I have now changed the Linux client IP address to be 192.168.1.2, but ping still does not work.